# Spring security RESTful path based role control

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

e.g.

```
/user/{userId}/* # Only user with userId and admin can access
/order/{orderId}/* # Only the order owner of orderId and admin can access
```

Current solution, the `@Current` annotation is a customized injection which is relate to the `token` passed to server.`@PathVariable("user-id") UserEntity user` is got from path with Spring-Data

```
@PreAuthorize("#user.id == #u?.id")
public UserDTO access(@P("user") @Current UserEntity requestUser,
                      @P("u") @PathVariable("user-id") UserEntity user)

@PreAuthorize("#user.id == #uid && (#order == null || #order?.user?.id == #uid)")
public Message access(@Current @P("user") UserEntity user,
                      @PathVariable("user-id") @P("uid") Long uid,
                      @PathVariable("order-id") @P("order") OrderEntity order)
```

We got too many annotation, is there any simple way to config them all ?

Tried

1. Use `.antMatchers("/user/[0-9]+/*").hasRole("ROLE_USER")` can not customize the user check.
2. AOP, too complicated, can no do url based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use method security to implement fine grained logic to auhtorize resource access. Url-based authentication in my opinion is effective only for simple use cases.

I would also suggest to use AOP with custom annotations to implement your method security (instead of using `@PreAuthorize`) if your authorization logic requires several lines of code...

For example you could intercept annotated method invocations:

```
@Before("@annotation(your.annotations.AllowedToOwner) && @annotation(ann)")
public void checkOwner(JoinPoint joinPoint, AllowedToOwner ann) throws Throwable {

    // check owner, throws AccessDeniedException if check fails...
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is only doable way.

Comment: @wener this is the approach I usually apply to my projects. Maybe there are better ways to achieve what you want, but I find this method very readable and effective.